# How do I cancel a statement if there is an error on laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, notifications, laravel-5.3

I use laravel 5.3

I collaborate it with a repository

My code like this :

```
public function addGuest($param)
{
    ...
    $guest = $this->user_repository->create($param);
    Notification::send($guest[1], new GuestRegistered($data));
    return $guest;
}
```

So I have 2 statement. There are create process and notification

On the code, if notification exist error, the first statement executed

I want if one of the statements errors then the 2 statements above are not executed

How can I do it?

Comment: then don't put those statements 'before' it (simple but prob what you were thinking) ... if its database related, you might be able to look into 'transactions' which allow rollbacks .. maybe

Comment: there are other concerns, these notifications could be async which means you wont know if they were successful when this code actually runs